# In Firebird database how do I grant a role to a user with the grant option?

Tags: sql, database, firebird, roles

I have a user that needs the grant option adding. I have tried the following command;

```
grant myrole to myuser with grant option
```

However I get the error;

```
Dynamic SQL Error SQL error code = -104 Token unknown - line 1, column 29 grant
```

I have also tried revoking the role and then granting the role again. But I get the same error.

I am only able to grant the role without the grant option. I have checked the manual for the correct syntax, but I cannot see what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hmm, seems to depend on exactly where in the manual you are looking. But, even with the keyword USER it still doesn't work.

Comment: Which Firebird version are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`GRANT`](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-privs-grant) clause `with grant option` is only for privileges, not for roles. For roles you need to use `with admin option`.

```
GRANT <role_granted>
TO <role_grantee_list> [WITH ADMIN OPTION]
[{GRANTED BY | AS} [USER] grantor]
```

> The optional `WITH ADMIN OPTION` clause allows the users specified in the user list to grant the role[s] specified to other users.

Comment: Finally got round to testing this. Initially it did not work, but I had to do revoke all on all from user first, then it worked.

Answer (score 2):

[Granting privileges](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-privs-grant) seems to allow the use of 'with grant option'

```
GRANT {
      <privileges> ON [TABLE] {tablename | viewname} 
      | EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE procname
          }
    TO <grantee_list>
      [WITH GRANT OPTION]} | [{GRANTED BY | AS} [USER] grantor];
```

but granting a role doesn't seem to allow 'with grant option'. It has the 'with admin option' which is why I presume the error occurred once it came across the word 'grant' rather than 'admin' after the word 'with'.

```
GRANT <role_granted>
TO <role_grantee_list> [WITH ADMIN OPTION]
[{GRANTED BY | AS} [USER] grantor]
```

Comment: I think you need to rephrase this answer, as you can do it (as the second part of your answer implies).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel  I wasn't sure if the 'with admin option' gave him what he wanted but from your answer I see that it does. So I have removed the misleading first sentence in my answer.

Comment: Yes, at the moment it does; this may change in the future, because I created ticket [CORE-5248](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-5248)